# Python - Pandas - SQL Query Params - Can't filter data without doubles quotes

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm getting some data from a database using pandas read sql query operations:

```
import pandas as pd
date_filter = '2020-01-01'
df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id>= {date_filter }", my_connection)
```

If I run this code the filter will not be applied and it brings all the data.
However, if I put a double quote on the variable:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id>= '{date_filter }'", my_connection)
```

It makes the filter correctly.

Why? Am I making any error?

Comment: This makes sense because in SQL you would filter on `'2020-01-01'`.

Comment: No you're not making a mistake, SQL doesn't like raw date strings without quotes because there's not an easy delimiter to recognize that it's a single token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap apostrophes around the variable, because without the variable, you would end up with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id>= 2020-09-08
```

this is invalid SQL. You need to wrap apostrophes around the value to have a valid syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id>= '2020-09-08'
```

This is the reason you need to wrap apostrophes around your template.

Answer (score 2):

Without quotes, I would guess the SQL parser may be taking the subtraction of year / month / day parts in your variable:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >= 2020-01-01

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >= 2018
```

And since most date times in databases are formatted seconds from epoch (`1970-01-01 00:00:00`). The human readable conversion of `2018` is a few minutes from epoch, specifically `Thursday, January 1, 1970 12:33:38 AM`. Hence, why nearly all your data is returned.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >= '1970-01-01 12:33:38'
```

As you learned, quoting literal date values works but an even better solution is [parameterization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) which is supported in [**`pandas.read_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html). To be clear, F-strings are not parameterization but simply a newer version of string interpolation. Also, do note the parameter placeholder differs depending on DB-API and the symbol should not be quoted or combined in any arithmetic or other operations.

```
# cxOracle
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >=  :1", 
                       my_connection, params=[date_filter])

# psycopg2, pymysql, pymssql
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >=  %s", 
                       my_connection, params=[date_filter])

# pyodbc, sqlite3, ibm_db, jaydebeapi
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_id >=  ?", 
                       my_connection, params=[date_filter])
```